# Can I email through a POST the contents of an HTML table that is populated by a seperate php database query?

Tags: php, html, email

I have a table that is populated with the results of a database query. I now want to send the contents of that table embedded in an email through a form post. However, I have been unable to pass the table into the $message of the php file resulting in an empty email. Any thoughts on how I can make this work?

HTML

```
<form method="post"  action="email.php" role="form">
                <table name="message" id="billing" class="sortable">
                <col width="450px">
                <col width="120px">
                <col width="120px">
                <col width="120px">
                <col width="120px">
                <div id="title"><h2>Media File Details</h2></div>
                <thead><th>File Name</th><th>Total Plays</th><th>Total Stores</th><th>Duration</th><th>Total Duration</th></thead>
                <tbody><?php include("billing.php")?></tbody>
                </table>
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

email.php

```
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'sender@mail.com';
$name = 'Recipient';
$email_address = 'some@email.com';
$message = $_POST['message'];

{
$to = $myemail;
$email_subject = "Customized media item report for : $name";
$email_body = "$message";
$headers = "From: $myemail\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
header('redirect to: somewebsite.html');
}
```

Comment: Since you're sending HTML by email, you should add the extra header: `$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html;';`

Comment: Well, your table is not an input field, how do you expect to pass that to PHP as $_POST field? You should be building that table in your email.php script.

Comment: I tried that, but all it does is echo the html code in the email, it does not execute billing.php to populate the table.

Comment: Cosmoonot - Your note convinced me to press further. I now have it working. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I combined the billing.php into the email.php and built the message variable through the results.